# $I$ nil ideal and $S/I$ is nil in $R/I$ then $S+I$ is nil.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Disclaimer: R is a unital ring, not necessarily commutative.

Let $I$ be a nil ideal and $S/I \subseteq R/I$ be a nil subset (every element is nilpotent) of $R/I$ where $S$ is a subset of $R$.

Show that $S+I$ is a nil subset of $R$.

Attempt: Let $s\in S, i\in I$. We have to show that $i+s$ is nilpotent. I can see that some power of $s$ must lie in $I$ but I don't see how this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can see that some power of  must lie in  but I don't see how this helps.

You are like a millimeter away from the solution.

Using your observation, $(i+s)^n=(\text{things with at least one $i$})+s^n\in I$.  But $I$ is a nil ideal... see the solution?

Comment: Thanks. Very clear. Should drink more coffee so I can solve these trivialities myself!

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Ugh, of course.  That is the picture I had in my mind but it did not come out in a correct way did it. Thanks you